# Is this a 略字 or 異体字 for 鼻?

Tags: kanji

Heya I came across the following and wasn't able to identify one character:

[image]

So far I've got "待てマントで自「？」ふくな", where ? is the character I can't quite identify.

Comment: It probably is "鼻をふくな" but 鼻 is written in the wrong way. I don't think a 略字 for 鼻 like this exists.

Comment: @naruto Though I don't believe it's what the writer wanted to write, the character [](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A2%8D%82) does exist ([source](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/kangxi/pic.php?f=zihai&p=1266)).